# White Border Around Fixed Position Header in Firefox

Tags: css, styles, stylesheet

I'm having a really frustrating issue with Firefox. I just rolled out an update to my site at socwall.com, and all of the browsers look great, except for this one issue with Firefox:

[image]

Firefox is rendering a white border along the top and left edges of my fixed position header. Strangely enough, if I hover over the element in Firebug and then hover away, the issue is fixed:

[image]

Is this something I need to bring up with the Firefox team, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

- Which version of Firefox are you using?
- Are you using any custom Firefox theme?

I am on `Beta Channel` with recent beta version 9 and as you can see in the attached screen-shot, I don't have it.

[image]

Comment: Ohhh that is encouraging. I'm on 8.0.1. Also, I am not using a custom theme.

Comment: @Krik: If you are using any custom theme, you could try disabling them? Also, from `Help` menu you could restart Firefox with all add-ons disabled.

Comment: Restarting Firefox with add-ons disabled fixes it. When disabling my add-ons and restarting one by one, I can't seem to find the culprit. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Krik: Are you using any custom themes and 3rd-party plugins? 

Press `Ctrl+Shift+A` or `Tools > Add-ons > Appearance` and switch to `Default`

You could also try disabling 3rd-party plug-ins by going into `Tools > Add-ons > Plugins`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `outline: 0` in your CSS.

Comment: No dice, looks like that isn't healing it